Is the North American /æ/ sound more like /a/ or /ɛ/?
I’m a foreigner living in North America, and:

I am fine with pronouncing the /ɛ/ sound, as in beg, men, and dead.

However, I’ve been struggling with the correct pronunciation of the /æ/ sound, as in bag, man, and dad.

In Brazilian Portuguese, we have /a/ and /ɛ/, but not /æ/.


Should I try to pronounce the /æ/ sound more like /a/ or /ɛ/ in order to be better understood by locals?

It's probably better to think of the American phoneme as /ɑ/ not /a/. It's a very low back sound, not a front sound here.

@tchrist I believe the asker is using /a/ to denote a phoneme in Brazilian Portuguese, not one in English.

@alphabet In Portuguese the /a/ phoneme is a mid vowel not a front vowel like English /ɛ/ and  /æ/, nor a back vowel like English  /ɑ/. So asking if a back vowel is “more like” a front vowel or a mid vowel may not be getting us far. European Portuguese actually has (or can have) a lowered and retracted [æ̈] allophone before /l/—but Brazilian Portuguese lacks this sound, so he probably has little to compare ours with.

I've called /a/ the sound that is very similar in Spanish and Italian for the letter 'a' (typically). I have the impression that a sound similar to /a/ is used in some English-speaking African countries, but I don't know which one.

@EduardoBandeira Thanks, now we can answer, provided it not get closed too quickly.

@tchrist I voted to move this to ELL but can retract that vote if you'd prefer it stay here.

It's really a sound in between /a/ and /ɛ/. So you don't want to pronounce it like either one.

The a in bag, man and dad sounds like the a in Rio de Janeiro as spoken in that link (British English).

@WeatherVane In what link is that demonstrated, and why does Insular English matter when he's asking about North American English? Remember how super different your vowels are from ours, especially in this particular matter. We have no trap–bath split and say both of those with a vowel you may not even have.

@tchrist it was a comment, not an answer. The voice is given in my link with a little loudspeaker icon which you click. With Insular English are your trying to marginalise the home of English? In USA they don't speak English but a peculiar American English. Similar to the Forth Bridge, as distinct from the Forth Road Bridge.

@WeatherVane You can’t use the pronunciation of the "a" in Rio de Janeiro for bad, dad, man because it's an unstressed syllable, so reduces to phonetic [ɐ]. As for insular, I really wish people would stop thinking that nasty, nasty thing which I would never say nor imply. Insular is merely the linguistic term for islandish and is used in many contexts similar to this one; consider the Insular Celtic languages vs the Continental ones. It means nothing more.

Come off it, insular implies something else. English has spread from England around the world.

@WeatherVane This is the professional term; it is not insultant. Which would you prefer that I use? Islandic perhaps? Claiming that Americans do not speak English really isn't kosher, you know.

How about the a in Bandeira?

Why don't you go over to Forvo and check those words under AmE? All this back and forth is somewhat nonsensical. https://forvo.com/search/man/en_usa/

After Eduardo's clarification that by /a/ from Brazilian Portuguese (a mid vowel) he meant something like the Spanish and Italian /a/ (also mid vowels), I can confirm that the American /æ/ phoneme is not like that.
Instead, it is a front vowel just like the /ɛ/ phoneme is, putting English ban closer to Ben than to barn, and likewise the stressed version of English can closer to Ken than to Kahn (whereas the unstressed can is just /kǝn/ not /kæn/).
But this tricky sound is also subject to numerous complex sound changes in various phonologic contexts and geographic regions. Please see the Wikipedia article on  “æ Raising” as well as our own questions about æ raising and tensing for more about this.
As to whether he would be more easily understood by North Americans if he pronounced bad as /bad/ or as /bɛd/, the answer is neither one would work for us. That’s because he’d be at risk of them thinking the first one is bod or bard, and he surely doesn’t want that.
Here’s my recommendation.
Try saying bed in two pieces: the first piece as what would in Portuguese be written bê with e fechado, then followed in the second piece by ǝd like the end of English words like bud or mud, so basically [beǝd].
That particular /æ/ variation can actually happen in some dialects here under AE Raising, and it might even sound like two syllables to you not a diphthong in one. But since it does happen here, they shouldn’t be confused if you say it that way.

In comments I had previously observed that in Portuguese the /a/ phoneme is a mid vowel not a front vowel like English /ɛ/ and  /æ/, nor a back vowel like English  /ɑ/. So asking if a back vowel is “more like” a front vowel or a mid vowel may not be getting us far. European Portuguese actually has (or can have) a lowered and retracted [æ̈] allophone before /l/—but Brazilian Portuguese lacks this sound, so he probably has little to compare ours with.

Good. So my question is: Would I be more easily understood by North Americans if I pronounced 'bad' as /bad/ or as /bɛd/?

@EduardoBandeira Probably neither. :( You're at risk of them thinking the first one is bod or bard, and you surely don't want that. Try saying bed in two pieces: the first as what would in Portuguese be written bê with e fechado, then followed in the second part by ǝd like the end of English words like bud or mud,  so basically [beǝd]. That particular /æ/ variation can actually happen in some dialects here under AE Raising, and it might even sound like two syllables to you not a diphthong in one. But since it does happen here, they shouldn't be confused if you say it that way.

Thank you, your answer is very helpful. I didn't downvote your answer; it was someone else.

@tchrist That would have the disadvantage of making you sound like you have a strong Midwestern accent, at least in regions where that pronunciation is uncommon enough to be quite striking.

@alphabet Or Southern. But so what? The goal is that that way it still won't risk confusing anybody with a bod.
